# How to create number input field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, input, textfield

I'm unable to find a way to create an input field in Flutter that would open up a numeric keyboard and should take numeric input only. Is this possible with Flutter material widgets? Some GitHub discussions seem to indicate this is a supported feature but I'm unable to find any documentation about it.

Comment: add keyboard type keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

Answer (score 708, accepted):

You can specify the number as [keyboardType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardType.html) for the [TextField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) using:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

Check my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new HomePage(),
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter your number"),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
              ], // Only numbers can be entered
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: But I can paste the Texts (Characters) on that field do you have any other options? @Rissmon Suresh

Comment: do not forget => import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Comment: Allows to put dot, space and paste emoji

Comment: Thanks guyz it is protected from any pastes of emojis/text

Comment: Note there is no done button on iOS - see here - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12220

Comment: inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly] is also required here ,as comma and dot can still be accepted here in the answer.

Comment: invalidCharacters = RegExp('[!@#%^&*(),.?":{}|<>&]'); use this as validation to prevent commas or you can use ''TextInputType.phone'' .

Comment: Deprecated: inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]. Instead use: inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]

Comment: @Eren You are right.It's [deprecated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter/digitsOnly.html)

Comment: @SamuelRickySaputro It's Working.. Check out this dartpad[https://dartpad.dev/?id=91345ed17dfb766167c49b52661b2688&null_safety=true] i created.

Answer (score 275):

For those who are looking for making `TextField` or `TextFormField` accept only numbers as input, try this code block :

for flutter 1.20 or newer versions

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
   // for below version 2 use this
 FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')), 
// for version 2 and greater youcan also use this
 FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly

  ],
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "whatever you want",
    hintText: "whatever you want",
    icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone)
  )
)
```

for earlier versions of 1.20

```dart
TextFormField(
    controller: _controller,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ],
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText:"whatever you want", 
        hintText: "whatever you want",
        icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone)
    )
)
```

**Note:** You need to import `services.dart` when using `FilteringTextInputFormatter`

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Comment: This is welcome to avoid the user to paste non digit strings (inputFormatters), thanks.

Comment: This works well even in Flutter_web as well. The reason being in in flutter_web we cannot enforce a numeric keyboard so restriction is the natural option. Thanks @BilalŞimşek

Comment: its deprecated now.

Comment: but when the non digit strings are stored in the vaiable, they are not just updated in the textField. When we press backspace we can understand it. How to code it in a way which only digits are strored in the controller.text?

Comment: @Bensal you can use RegExp(r'[0-9]') for controller.text also.

Comment: @BilalŞimşek Thank you for your reply, but i dint find a way to add it through a controller, can you show me the code?

Comment: I work with flutter 2.1.0, This still works as well.
`inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ],`

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly  is deprecated in Flutter 2.2.2, instead use inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly] to allow digits only (no commas, spaces, or # are allowed)

Comment: To prevent people from typing multiple decimals the regexp `r'^\d+\.?\d*'` works well.

Comment: For flutter 2/3  ```inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly ]```

Answer (score 92):

Through this option you can strictly restricted another char with out number.

```
 inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

For using above option you have to import this

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

using this kind of option user can not paste char in a textfield

Comment: this is the actual comprehensive answer. without the formatters just setting keyboard not enough.

Comment: if i want just decimal and digits. how do add the "." into the whitelist of formatter?

Comment: @shababhsiddique did you find the answer?

Comment: @anoop4real yes i just use TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow((RegExp("[.0-9]")))
        ],
      ) There is a "." in the regExp

Comment: @shababhsiddique it allows for multiple "."s . i want to accept double numbers. any idea how?

Comment: FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d*\.?\d*$'))

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter is depricated.

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter is depricated change to FilteringTextInputFormatter https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335837/9576680

Answer (score 46):

Set the keyboard and a validator

```
String numberValidator(String value) {
  if(value == null) {
    return null;
  }
  final n = num.tryParse(value);
  if(n == null) {
    return '"$value" is not a valid number';
  }
  return null;
}

new TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number, 
    validator: numberValidator, 
    textAlign: TextAlign.right
    ...
```

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html

Comment: Got error: Local variable num cannot be referenced before it is declared

Comment: Ok, the name `num` for the variable does not work. The name needs to be changed

Comment: From docs: The onError parameter is deprecated and will be removed. Instead of num.parse(string, (string) { ... }), you should use num.tryParse(string) ?? (...).

Answer (score 36):

To avoid paste not digit value, add after

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

this code :

```
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]
```

from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html

Answer (score 20):

If you need to use a **double** number:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.,]')),],
onChanged: (value) => doubleVar = double.parse(value),
```

`RegExp('[0-9.,]')` allows for digits between 0 and 9, also comma and dot.

`RegExp('[0-9.,-]')` allows for digits between 0 and 9, also comma, dot and minus sign (for negative numbers).

`double.parse()` converts from string to double.

Don't forget you need:
`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

You can check and test a full **demo** at [this dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0e2c0c9572715519f0e77ef0f5f2f73b)

If you want to allow minus sign only at the start of the string:

```
final RegExp _myPattern = RegExp(r'^-?[\d,.]*$');
(...)
TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
  (TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return _myPattern.hasMatch(newValue.text)
        ? newValue
         : oldValue;
   },
 ),
```

You can check and test the full **demo2** at [this other dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=96ade6071bd212359a644325157b9865)

Comment: negative number handling is missing in your solution

Comment: @cabbi thanks for your comment. answer updated :-)

Comment: with [0-9.,-] you can insert the '-' sign at any position (e.g. 12-34.01). should be something like: ^-?[0-9.,] but this regex expression is not working as I would expect

Comment: "FilteringTextInputFormatter typically shouldn't be used with RegExps that contain positional matchers (^ or $) " 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html

Comment: @cabbi I've updated the answer with an option to allow minus sign only at the start of the string

Answer (score 19):

For those who need to work with **money format** in the text fields:

To use only: , *(comma)* and . *(period)*

and block the symbol: - *(hyphen, minus or dash)*

as well as the: ⌴ *(blank space)*

In your TextField, just set the following code:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[\\-|\\ ]'))],
```

The simbols hyphen and space will still appear in the keyboard, but will become blocked.

Comment: Do you know how to allow only one comma or period?

Comment: @HeddieFranco read about regex https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 14):

The `TextField` widget is required to set `keyboardType: TextInputType.number,`
and `inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]` to accept numbers only as input.

```
     TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ], // Only numbers can be entered
          ),
```

#### [Example in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/91345ed17dfb766167c49b52661b2688?)

[image: screenshot of dartpad]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: HomePage(),
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return HomePageState();
      }
    }
    
    class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("This Input accepts Numbers only"),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.greenAccent, width: 5.0),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5.0),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ], // Only numbers can be entered
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text("You can test be Typing"),
                ],
              )),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this two attributes together with TextFormField

```
 TextFormField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.number
         inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
```

It's allow to put only numbers, no thing else ..

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html

Answer (score 8):

As the accepted answer states, specifying `keyboardType` triggers a numeric keyboard:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

Other good answers have pointed out that a simple regex-based formatter can be used to allow only whole numbers to be typed:

```
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
],
```

The problem with this is that the regex only matches one symbol at a time, so limiting the number of decimal points (e.g.) cannot be achieved this way.

Also, others have also shown that if one wants *validation* for a decimal number, it can be achieved by using a `TextFormField` and it's `validator` parameter:

```
new TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number, 
    validator: (v) => num.tryParse(v) == null ? "invalid number" : null, 
    ...
```

The problem with this is that it cannot be achieved interactively, but only at form submission time.

---

I wanted to *allow only decimal numbers to be typed*, rather than validated later. My solution is to write a custom formatter leveraging `int.tryParse`:

```dart
/// Allows only decimal numbers to be input.
class DecimalNumberFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Allow empty input and delegate formatting decision to `num.tryParse`.
    return newValue.text != '' && num.tryParse(newValue.text) == null
        ? oldValue
        : newValue;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, one can use a regex for the custom formatter, which would apply to the whole input, not just a single symbol:

```dart
/// Allows only decimal numbers to be input. Limits decimal plates to 3.
class DecimalNumberFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Allow empty input.
    if (newValue.text == '') return newValue;

    // Regex: can start with zero or more digits, maybe followed by a decimal
    // point, followed by zero, one, two, or three digits.
    return RegExp('^\\d*\\.?\\d?\\d?\\d?\$').hasMatch(newValue.text)
        ? newValue
        : oldValue;
  }
}
```

This way, I can also limit the number of decimal plates to 3.

Answer (score 6):

Here is code for actual Phone keyboard on Android:

Key part: `keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,`

```dart
  TextFormField(
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 24
    ),
    controller: _phoneNumberController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixText: "+1 ",
      labelText: 'Phone number'),
    validator: (String value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Phone number (+x xxx-xxx-xxxx)';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 6):

Number type only

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

And more option with number pad

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true,signed: false)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add this to your `TextFormField`

```
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')), ],
```

**Example,**

```
TextFormField(
        controller: textController,
        onChanged: (value) {
         print(value);
        },
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 6):

To Create number input field, You just need to give following property inside your **textfield** or **textformfield**.

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number, // Set the keyboard type to number
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter a number',
  ),
);
```

Happy Fluttering!

Answer (score 4):

You can Easily  change the Input Type using the [keyboardType](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/keyboardType.html) Parameter 
and you have a lot of possibilities check the documentation [TextInputType](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html)
so you can use the number or phone value

```
 new TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.number)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```dart
TextFormField(
     keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Text("Enter your number: ")
     ),
     initialValue: "5",
     onSaved: (input) => _value = num.tryParse(input),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

`keyboardType: TextInputType.number` would open a num pad on focus, I would clear the text field when the user enters/past anything else.

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
onChanged: (String newVal) {
    if(!isNumber(newVal)) {
        editingController.clear();
    }
}

// Function to validate the number
bool isNumber(String value) {
    if(value == null) {
        return true;
    }
    final n = num.tryParse(value);
    return n!= null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For number input or numeric keyboard you can use keyboardType: TextInputType.number

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:'Amount'),
    controller: TextEditingController(
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter Amount';
    }
  },
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add input format with keyboard type, like this

```
TextField(
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ],// Only numbers can be entered
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
   );
```

Answer (score 2):

U can Install package **intl_phone_number_input**

```
dependencies:
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.5.2+2
```

and try this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl_phone_number_input/intl_phone_number_input.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String initialCountry = 'NG';
  PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'NG');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
              onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                print(number.phoneNumber);
              },
              onInputValidated: (bool value) {
                print(value);
              },
              selectorConfig: SelectorConfig(
                selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              ),
              ignoreBlank: false,
              autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
              selectorTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              initialValue: number,
              textFieldController: controller,
              inputBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                formKey.currentState.validate();
              },
              child: Text('Validate'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getPhoneNumber('+15417543010');
              },
              child: Text('Update'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void getPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    PhoneNumber number =
        await PhoneNumber.getRegionInfoFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 'US');

    setState(() {
      this.number = number;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

[image: image:]

Answer (score 2):

I need en IntegerFormField with a controll of min/max. And the big problem is that OnEditingComlete is not called when the focus changes. Here is my solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:vs_dart/vs_dart.dart';

class IntegerFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  final int value, min, max;
  final InputDecoration decoration;
  final ValueChanged<TextEditingController> onEditingComplete;
  IntegerFormField({@required this.value, InputDecoration decoration, onEditingComplete, int min, int max})
      : min = min ?? 0,
        max = max ?? maxIntValue,
        onEditingComplete = onEditingComplete ?? ((_) {}),
        decoration = decoration ?? InputDecoration()
  ;

  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<IntegerFormField> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.text = widget.value.toString();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onEditingComplete() {
    {
      try {
        if (int.parse(controller.text) < widget.min)
          controller.text = widget.min.toString();
        else if (int.parse(controller.text) > widget.max)
          controller.text = widget.max.toString();
        else
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      } catch (e) {
        controller.text = widget.value.toString();
      }
      widget.onEditingComplete(controller);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: widget.decoration,
      ),
      onFocusChange: (value) {
        if (value)
          controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: controller.value.text.length);
        else
          onEditingComplete();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your keyboardType to TextInputType.number,

Eg: keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

```
         TextFormField(
            controller: yourcontroller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Mobile',
              suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                child:
                Icon(Icons.phone_outlined, color: Color(0xffff4876)),
              ),
            ),
            validator: (text) {
              if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your Mobile No.';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for numeric keyboard :
 **keyboardType: TextInputType.phone**   When you add this code in textfield it will open numeric keyboard.

```
  final _mobileFocus = new FocusNode();
  final _mobile = TextEditingController();


     TextFormField(
          controller: _mobile,
          focusNode: _mobileFocus,
          maxLength: 10,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            counterText: "",
            counterStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
            hintText: "Mobile",
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 15.0.
            ),
          ),
          style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 15.0,
           ),
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is code for actual Phone keyboard in Flutter:

```
     //Mobile
            const TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.phone), hintText: 'Mobile'),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are all details on how to add numeric keybord, How to do validations, How to add stylings, and other stuff in dart/flutter.
I hope it can help you to learn in a better way.

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              maxLength: 10,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Enter Number Please';
                }
                
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.smartphone),
                prefixText: '+92',
                labelText: 'Enter Phone Number',
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 2, color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .primaryColor,
                    )
                ),
                focusColor: Theme
                    .of(context)
                    .primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0.0-9.9]')),
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to allow phone number that starts with + (plus) sign. Try this

```dart
TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
  /// Add this
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true, signed: true),
  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\+?\d*'))],
  ///
),
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this plugin it's very easy with this plugin

```
enter code here
```

link: https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input/example