# Flutter keyboard on screen all the time as a widget?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

- Is it possible to use the keyboard as a widget ?
- here are some edited screenshots to show what i mean:

[keyboard1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5zq2.png)
[keyboard2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4HBq.png)

edit : i want it to stay at that place and use it to input numbers to a textfield, i don't want to move it or anything.

Comment: For number keyboards, you can easily build your own widget: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51623027/2461957

Comment: To display the real keyboard permanently, you would have to do some heave customizations in the lower layers of Flutter.

Comment: This question doesn't describe what you want to do, other than `keyboard as widget`. Please explain what you mean by `as a widget` - do you want to be able to move it around, or customize it, or show a helper widget when it's open?

Answer (score 0):

Good thing there is an existing Flutter plugins that you can use. Check the [numeric_keyboard](https://pub.dev/packages/numeric_keyboard) plugins. This will do exactly what you are trying to achieve.

[image]

If you need more customization, you can check [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions).