# Digit only TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im am working on an app that requires a price input in `¥` and as such has no decimal places. 
If we use `keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions()` we can get a number pad input.
If we use `validator: (input) { }` we can check if input is valid but we cannot prevent it.

The problem is we can save a draft that will not need validation.
So it is better for us to only allow digit input in the first place.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Digits Only',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              autovalidate: true,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (input) {
                final isDigitsOnly = int.tryParse(input);
                return isDigitsOnly == null
                    ? 'Input needs to be digits only'
                    : null;
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent certain text input and only allow digits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create number input field in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577781/how-to-create-number-input-field-in-flutter)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Yep, you can use the `inputFormatters` attribute and add the `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly` expression

```
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


  TextFormField(
          ...
          inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
        )
```

You can find more info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html

After flutter 1.12, `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` was deprecated and you are running a newer version, use :

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html

Comment: But how to force the keyboard to digit only?

Comment: Oh sorry I found this ```keyboardType: TextInputType.number,```

Comment: Thank you @diegoveloper , I used inputFormatters , with keyboardType attibutes together , thanks alot

Comment: @SunaArun sure :) , follow my twitter to learn more about Flutter :) https://twitter.com/diegoveloper

Comment: How can I limit the digits from 1-3. So only digits `1`,`2`,`3` can be typed

Answer (score 31):

With `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` deprecated and using a **double** number:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.,]+')),],
onChanged: (value) => doubleVar = double.parse(value),
```

`RegExp('[0-9.,]+')` allows for digits between 0 and 9, also comma and dot.

You can use `RegExp('([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)')` to allow digits and only one dot. See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33955040/9524409).

`double.parse()` converts from string to double.

Don't forget you need:
`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: I have an issue though, How to allow only one dot?
Like this example (8.88)   and to prevent something like this (8..88) and also prevent something like this (8.88.8) etc?

Comment: Hi @xSuperMu. Please try this RegExp: ^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?) as seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33955040/9524409

Comment: RegExp('([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)') doesn't seem to work. This works:

RegExp(r'(^\d*\.?\d*)') see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61214872/regex-for-double-numbers-in-dart

Answer (score 19):

An update on or after April 2021:

```
TextField(
   inputformatter: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
      ],
   textInputType: TextInputType.number,
```

Other examples of the use of input formatters include:

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'[/\\]')),
  ],
)
```

OR

```
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^ ?\d*')),]
   inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(' ')]
```

OR

```
Other options include:

> lowercase letters: a-z
> capital letters: A-Z
> lowercase vowels accented: á-ú
> capital vowels accented: Á-Ú
> numbers: 0-9
> space : (space)
```

So in the above case you can have

```
inputFormatters: [
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-z A-Z á-ú Á-Ú 0-9]"))
      ]
```

Comment: Edit for the first (edit queue is full..) :

TextField(
   inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
      ],
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

Answer (score 4):

If I am not getting you wrong simply use it `keyboardType: TextInputType.number,` in textfield.

Comment: `TextInputType.number`can't be used as solution here because it is still allow decimal place for example : 14.50

Comment: What for flutter web ?

Comment: There is a TextInputType.phone option too