# How to save an empty TextFormField to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

If only the first field and/or last field is left blank, then the onpress saves. However, if any that should contain numbers are blank, it will not save. I've tried adding `?? " "` as well as `?? null`, yet it's still not working.

```
onPressed: () async {
              final uid =
                  await TheProvider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();

              //save data to firebase

              widget.contact.name = oneController.text;
              widget.contact.phoneNumber = int.parse(twoController.text);
              widget.contact.location = threeController.text;
              widget.contact.rating = int.parse(fourController.text);
              widget.contact.instagram = fiveController.text;
              widget.contact.birthday = int.parse(sixController.text);
              widget.contact.notes = sevenController.text;

              await db
                  .collection("userData")
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection("Contacts")
                  .add(widget.contact.toJson());
```

The Map

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'Name': name,
    'PhoneNumber': phoneNumber,
    'Location': location,
    'Rating': rating,
    'Instagram': instagram,
    'Birthday': birthday,
    'Notes': notes,
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int.tryParse` for integer TextFormFields

Answer (score 1):

Empty value or null value are not supported by Firebase. I could not find this in their documentation. But it's obvious null and empty values are the same as the record not existing, that might be the reason they don't support it.
You can yourself initialise variables in your model to empty strings in your model.
Note :- You will get null when you query the path

Comment: Hi Arpit, what would the code look like for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore will always store numbers as [doubles](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types), so it will not accept values such as `null` or an empty string on a field with a number datatype. Like @Arpit said, what I can also suggest is that you initialize variables and pass a default value for the following with `0`:

- phoneNumber
- rating
- birthday

or create a [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778266/digit-only-textformfield-in-flutter/51778460) on the following TextFormField to only accept numbers.

Comment: Adding `?? 0` to each of those 3 variables did not work, I'm afraid. Would it be easier to code it to not save a field if it is left empty by the user?

Comment: I would suggest that you go and try it and see what works best on your use case.