# Flutter TextInputType.number is not forcing a number only keyboard

Tags: flutter

I don't understand what I'm missing here. I put TextInputType to number, and can still type any letter, special character and even an emoji. I have also tried making the child a TextInputType.numberWithOptions() widget, and it opens the same keyboard. Is this just a bug on my phone? P20 Pro

```
      Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('TextInputType.number:'),
            Flexible(
                child: TextField(
              maxLength: 3,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            )),
          ],
        )
```

[image: Should be numbers only]

Comment: `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` is showing number keyboard for me. Try to uninstall and reinstall the app again. Also try to use some other keyboard then SwiftKey.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To Only Enable Numbers - You need to add - `inputFormatters:` also adding -  `keyboardType:` won't help standalone.

Code:

```
TextField(
          maxLength: 3,
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          ],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        ),
```

Comment: This does make it so that the field doesn't accept anything but a number, but the keyboard still opens fully where I can press any character. Its an improvement for sure but I would really like it to just open like [this number only keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578197/8061908)

Comment: @MilesAdamson - Can you try it on different phone or Emulator & see the what keyboard comes up.

Comment: It appears it is an issue with my phone, P20 Pro. It works as expected on other phones, where they keyboard is only numbers. But your addition of WhitelistingTextInputFormatter is still great, thanks

Answer (score 12):

The approach above in [anmol.majhail's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55349535/7145285) answer is deprecated as of Flutter 2.0. Flutter recommends a shift from `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.*` to `FilteringTextInputFormatter.*`. As such, in order to achieve the same effect in a Flutter 2.0 app follow the example in the code excerpt below.

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 3,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
  ],
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
),
```

Comment: Not worked for me on samsung  phone chrome

Answer (score 0):

***Use this as older one is Depressed***

```
maxLength: 10,
inputFormatters: [
   // only accept letters from 0 to 9
   FilteringTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r'[0-9]'), allow: true)
   // Using for Text Only ==>    (RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'))
],
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

Answer (score 0):

TextFormField(

```
                       keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                       inputFormatters:  <TextInputFormatter> [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,                          
                        ],
                       decoration: const InputDecoration(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                       labelText: "TextInputType.number:", prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.wallet),
                       ),
                       maxLength: 10,
                       
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `FocusNode` then delete it. Now it's working fine.