# Recommended Flutter keyboard type to enter a hex string?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, hex

Is there a good keyboard type to use in flutter to enter a hex number?

I tried all the ones I could find and nothing had digits and characters without making me shift/long press to get the digits

Here was the closest question I found to this:

[How to create number input field in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577781/how-to-create-number-input-field-in-flutter)

Comment: I'm going to start working with this.  The "custom footer" example where he has color entry widgets I think is going to be just what I need: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions