# How to accept only numbers in TextFormFields?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to accept only numbers in `TextFormField`s. I have designed a `TextFormField` for accepting phone numbers. I have changed the keyboard type.

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
```

But, it can also accept special symbols or can paste other inputs also.
[Keyboard screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Pmn.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create number input field in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577781/how-to-create-number-input-field-in-flutter)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try below code, refer [FilteringTextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html)

import below library

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Your Widget: 1st Way

```
    TextFormField(
       keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
       inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
    ),
```

Your Widget: 2nd Way (Using [RegExp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) )

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
      RegExp("[0-9]"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try used input formatter

```
import 'package:flutter/src/services/text_formatter.dart';

TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      inputFormatters:
      [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
      ]
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use FilteringTextInputFormatter.

```
 TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ], // Only numbers can be entered
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your TextFormField add:

```
inputFormatters: [
   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
        RegExp("[0-9]")),
   ],
```

You can also modify RegExp for supporting any kind of input characters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, This could Work:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
```

Comment: When using this, actually I can move to text keyboard and write text to field.