# How can I put a specific keyboard type to an autocomplete flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I modify the input keyboard that comes out for an autocomplete from alphanumeric to numeric only?

Comment: hi, try checking on this page maybe there is someone who discusses this problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577781/how-to-create-number-input-field-in-flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
   // for below version 2 use this
 FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')), 
// for version 2 and greater youcan also use this
 FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly

  ],
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "whatever you want",
    hintText: "whatever you want",
    icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone)
  )
)
```

**use  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,**