How to open keyboard with spacial characters/numbers first on Flutter
Is there on Flutter a way to open the keyboard with the special characters/numbers view first, with the possibility to switch back to text characters?

Similar this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577781/how-to-create-number-input-field-in-flutter?rq=2 ?

no, he wants a numeric only keyboard, i want a normal keyboard (text/number/special characters) but which is first displayed with the number/special characters view, not the text one

There is no way to open the keyboard with the special characters/numbers view first in Flutter.
But if you want, you can make the TextField contain only special characters/numbers with the code below.
TextField(
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
            RegExp(r'[0-9+\-.,:;/*#@!?$%&()]')),
      ],
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter your text here',
      ),

